# GetFullPathNameA does not return Path of DLL

Tags: c++, c

How Do i get the full path of a DLL on a Windows PC? It just shows a blank Console program and nothing else

Code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    TCHAR full_path[MAX_PATH];
    LPSTR info = GetFullPathName(TEXT("freddie.dll"), MAX_PATH, full_path, NULL);
    printf("%s",info);
}
```

Comment: Why use TCHAR? Why not just use Unicode everywhere?

Comment: @DietrichEpp, crashes.

Comment: "warning C4047: 'initializing': 'LPSTR' differs in levels of indirection from 'DWORD'"

Comment: changed from LPSTR to DWORD it still crashes, @WeatherVane

Comment: Well how the devil do you think `printf` takes `DWORD` as format string? ... or as an arguemnt to `%s` format?

Comment: Please [RTM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx). **"If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in TCHARs, of the string copied to lpBuffer, not including the terminating null character."**

Comment: @WeatherVane, sorry i missed the %s, hence when i decided to print, i didnt get the path, i have put that, still crashes. i am using code blocks.

Comment: Please read the comments, and the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx), very carefully before you make random changes.

Comment: How does this even compile?  `GetFullPathName` returns a `DWORD`, not an `LPSTR`

Comment: Of course it crashes ... you're trying to print the length of the path with %s, rather than printing the path (full_path).

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your return type is wrong. It returns a `DWORD` which indicates the length of the string which is copied into the given buffer without counting the terminating `'\0'` character. The [GetFullPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation is very clear about that. Also there is an example of using the function.

And even if you changed your return type to `DWORD`. How should `printf` print a `DWORD` with the format specifier `%s`.

So here is a working example as C code because your code is C even though your tags include C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
   TCHAR full_path[MAX_PATH];
   DWORD string_len = GetFullPathName (TEXT("freddie.dll"),
                                       MAX_PATH,
                                       full_path,
                                       NULL);
   printf ("Length of full path string: %lu\n"
           "Full path: '%s'",
           (unsigned long) string_len,
           full_path);
}
```

Comment: Hi @RealMary if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.